# Клиентское приложение Telegram

Tags: c#, wpf, хранение-данных

Доброго времени суток! Загорелся желанием реализовать клиентское API Телеграмма, но в ходе разработке столкнулся с проблемой "memory leak". Все чаты, сообщения, контакты на данный момент хранятся в оперативной памяти, со временем показатель только возрастает. Соответственно вопрос: какие есть решения для такого рода задач?

Comment: Утечки памяти это достаточно серьёзная тема.  В общем виде информации может на целую книгу собраться. Думаю стоит привести проблемный код, предварительно воспользовавшись специальными утилитами для поиске утечек.

Comment: Для начала отделить мух от котлет, то есть рост памяти из-за данных от реальных утечек памяти. Для данных можно применять компрессию или хранение не в памяти. Для утечек смотреть инструментами что есть в памяти, а быть не должно и кто удерживает ресурс в памяти. И раз это wpf, то не забыть про виртуализацию в списочных контролах.

Comment: @vitidev спасибо большое!